# Validate a date in Laravel to be 6 days after another date field

Tags: laravel, date

I am working on a Laravel form field and have added 2 date input fields (departure-date and return-date). I am trying to create a custom backend validation in Laravel whereby the departure-date must be after now while the return-date must be 6 days after departure-date. Kindly assist?

**Validation parameters**

```
'departure_date' => 'required|date|after:now',

//Must be 6 days after departure date
'return_date' => 'required|date|after:departure_date + 6 day',
```

**Validation Logic I am using**

```
//Added at the top of the controller
use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

//Controller code
  public
    function validatePlanEntries(Request $request)
    {   
        $validation = $this->validate($request, [
            'departure_date' => 'required|date|after:now',

            //Must be 6 days after departure date
            'return_date' => ['required', 'date', function ($attribute, $value, $fail) {
                        if (strtotime($value) < strtotime(request('departure_date')) + 518400) {
                            $fail('Departure date invalid');
                        }
                    }
            ]
        ]
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Closure` solution.

```
$validator = \Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'departure_date' => 'required|date|after:now',

    //Must be 6 days after departure date
    'return_date' => ['required', 'date', function ($attribute, $value, $fail) {
                if (strtotime($value) < strtotime(request('departure_date')) + 518400 /* 6*24*60*60 */) {
                    $fail('Departure date invalid');
                }
            }
        ],
    ]
);
```

*EDIT*

You dont need to add the `FormRequest` on top and you're missing a cracket in your code.

```
function validatePlanEntries(Request $request)
{
    $validator = \Validator::make($request, [
        'departure_date' => 'required|date|after:now',

        //Must be 6 days after departure date
        'return_date' => ['required', 'date', function ($attribute, $value, $fail) {
            if (strtotime($value) < strtotime(request('departure_date')) + 518400) {
                $fail('Departure date invalid');
            }
        }]
    ]);
    if ($validator->fails()) {
        //return errors in $validation->error();
    }
    //else continue
}
```

Comment: ,, I have tried your 2nd suggecstion but am getting this error  **Object of class Closure could not be converted to string**

Comment: wrote `start_at` instead of `departure_date`. edited the answer. And the second solution  only works in a Class that extends `Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest::class` in the `rules()` method.

Comment: Am still getting the same error as I indicated above,, according to your suggestion am adding this line of code at the top of the controller `use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;`   next  I have added the first solution exactly as it is in your code but I get this error **Object of class Closure could not be converted to string** and am using Larvel version 5.4

Comment: @N696,, Trying to understand your code,, should I dd it inside validate method in my controller or a different file then import it cause am using Laravel version 5.4

Comment: @Patweb use the first solution in the validate method in your controler

Comment: ,, I use the first solution,, am getting this errror **Object of class Closure could not be converted to string** am using version 5.4 of Laravel

Comment: you're not putting the rules in an array `['required', 'date', function()]` !!

Comment: ,, Please check the updated question,, I have added the code am using in the controller according to your solution..

Comment: @Patweb edited the solution. it's in the second part. forget about the `Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest`

Comment: Thanks alot for your help,,, but the code still throws the same error of **(1/1) ErrorException
Object of class Closure could not be converted to string**

Comment: my bad, when creating custom rules you can use `$this->validate`, didn't see it at forst. edited again

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
$date = Carbon\Carbon::parse($date_from);
$sixdays = $date->addDays(6);
```

and set this rule

```
$rule['return_date'] = 'required|date|before:'.$sixdays
$message['return_date.before'] = 'This field is must before 6 days of starts date';
```

Comment: @ShaiendraGupta,,, Is there any logic I can use without using carbon,, am getting errors time installing carbon via composer

Comment: use this `date('Y-m-d', strtotime($yourDatehere. ' + 6 days'));`

Comment: According to your suggestion,, This is the code I have added `'return_date' => 'required|date|date('Y-m-d', strtotime(departure_date. ' + 6 days'))',` but it is throwing error of  **Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'Y' (T_STRING), expecting ']'**

Comment: you are dooing wrong way you have to dinamicaly add this fields like this `$rule['return_date'] = 'required|date|before:'.date('Y-m-d', strtotime(departure_date. ' + 6 days'));

Comment: updated answer please check and accept also so other can get it

Comment: Am confused with your code  seems you have changed it,, I had requested for an alternative solution to carbon since I was having error while installing carbon via composer

Comment: you have to make an $messages array of validation messages where you can set validation messages for your rule and access it with . oprator like retundate.required,retun_data.date and so on you can follow https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation#working-with-error-messages for mode details

Comment: I got you,, my concern is this line of code `$date = Carbon\Carbon::parse($date_from);
$sixdays = $date->addDays(6);`  how can I use it to get the departure date of the user  then add 6 days after it without using carbon.. I have a problem with carbon installation..

Comment: yes and you have to concatinate that date to validation rule before and also have to make an message of that  rule